# mysql concurrency

Tags: mysql

sorry if my question has been asked before or if it's too obvious but i really need to clear this. thanks for your help.

in a multi-user interface, if the same transaccion from different users arrive to server at the same time, what will happen?

i have the next table:

```
create table table_x (
  cod char(2) not null,
  desc varchar(45) not null,
  primary key (cod)
);
```

where these calls arrive at the same time to the server:

```
call sp_s('1','a');
call sp_s('1','b');
call sp_s('1','c');
```

what sp_s (in param_a char(2), in param_b varchar(45)) does is:

```
declare var_count tinyint default 0;

set var_count=
(select count(*) 
from table_x 
where cod=param_a);

if(var_count=0) then
insert into table_x values (param_a, param_b);
else
update table_x set desc=param_b
where cod=param_a;
end if;
```

if the registry doesn't exists it inserts it, but if it exists the sp updates it.

is this a good way to do it without using autoincrement?
whats the best way to avoid concurrency if i'm not using auto_increment?

thanks very much for your time.

Comment: there should be locks in a DBMS to handle these cases of concurrency

Comment: The problem is when two concurrent scripts wants to insert new item. They both will read that such item does not exist and both will try to insert it. You cannot lock not existent record in this case, but locking all table is just not cool.

Comment: In PostgreSQL I have used function `pg_advisory_lock` to overcome such issues. Before select I obtain the advisory lock by integer value I'm working with, then I'm sure the block isn't executed simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on transaction isolation level. You can however use insert into... on duplicate update, and unique index on cod.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out SELECT... FOR UPDATE which issues row level locks it may help you out, but I can't remember the details.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Alternatively instead of using INSERT and UPDATE you could use

`REPLACE into table_x values (param_a, param_b);`

Which will insert a row if one doesn't exist, or replace the values in the existing row.

Comment: It won't help in case the record does not exist. There is nothing to lock then.

Comment: Innodb uses "next key" locking and "gap locking" on the index to get round that problem (the phantom problem) http://techsoftcomputing.com/MySql%20ref/innodb-next-key-locking.html